# How do I change the line-height with this code?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```
<font color="#FFFFFF">
    <span style="float: left; position: relative; top: 25px; left:100px">
        text here<br>and more text here....
    </span>
</font>
```

Comment: This is unclear, what tag do you want to change the line-height of? With CSS, you can just do "line-height: 7px;" or whatever.

Comment: You want to wrap the whole thing in a `<marquee>`, and then put that in a few tables to control the line height :P

Comment: Im tring to add a paragraph to my header and the spacing between the lines are just a bit to big and I was hoping I could decrease that space?

Comment: The `font` element has been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT) long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there's a more imperative style associated with that element somewhere else in the cascade? Load that sucker up in Chrome and inspect the element via Web Developer extension - it will show the computed style on that element, and any overridden styles.

**EDIT:**

In response to comments:

```
<p style="line-height:1.2em;">Your text here</p>
```

That should do it, or adjust the 1.2em upward by small amounts. Remember though, this will only apply the line height style to that specific `<p>` tag. If you can /need to / want to be consistent, apply that `style="line-height:1.2em;"` to the paragraph's containing element, like:

```
<div style="line-height:1.2em;">
    <p>Paragraph 1 will have the same line-height as</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Im tring to add a paragraph to my header and the spacing between the lines are just a bit to big and I was hoping I could decrease that space?

Comment: If you want to add a paragraph, there's a tag for that. It's P, not SPAN and certainly not FONT. You can set the line-height property with the style attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true usage. I think the true usage is;

```
<span><font></font></span>
```

But you should try this;

```
<style>
.class1{
height: 100px;
width: 250px;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
font: normal 12px Verdana;
line-height: 100px;
}
</style>

<div class="class1">your text message is here...</div>
```

you can use another way for line-height in font property;

```
font: normal 12px/100px Verdana;
```

Comment: The `font` element has been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT) long ago.

Comment: You're right, I know. But I want to show potential true usage as hierarchy. Like this;
<a href="#"><div>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div></a> -> <div><a href="#">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>

Comment: I believe it also has to be a block element for line-height to work.